# What is the best way to return reference to a constant sized array of pointers?

Tags: c++

I have an array of pointers declared as a class member like this:

```
class Bar
{
private:
  static constexpr int SIZE = 10;    
  Foo* m[SIZE];
}
```

In one of my class methods, I would like to return a pointer (or preferably, a reference) to this array. The array has a known size at compile time, but I am keeping track of how many items I have put in there (it is a buffer of stuff).

What is the best way to return a reference to this array in C++11 ?

Here are the things I have tried:

```
GetArray(Foo* &f[], unsigned &size) const
```

I like the syntax because it makes it clear that the reference value is an array of pointers, but this gives a compiler error: `Declared as array of references of type Foo*`

```
GetArray(Foo** &f, unsigned &size) const
{
  f = m;
  size = mSize;
}
```

Gives me: Error: assigning to `Foo **' from incompatible type Foo *const[10]`. Casting `mFoo` to `(Foo**)` alleviates the error, but IMHO, this is not elegant.

Comment: If you're keeping track of how many items you put in it...what would be wrong with a `std::vector` which you give a constructor hint saying how big to allocate it under the hood?  The vector holds the size and you get all the goodness like proper iteration and generic algorithms and such.

Comment: @HostileFork or, for that matter, a `std::array`?

Comment: std::array/vector seems like a very elaborate way to do it.

Comment: @NikBougalis AFAIK if you use a `std::array` then you don't get a variable size tracked.  *(Note there is no std::array push_back, for instance.)*  He's describing a scenario where the array has a fixed capacity *but* he wants to track how much of that capacity is being used.  That's what std::vector is for; and is better than decoupling the "how much I'm using" out into a separate thing you track in another variable.

Comment: @ThomasKejser If by 'elaborate' you mean well-thought out, reusable, and supported by a robust standard...yes, it's pretty elaborate!  But unless you have a very good reason to avoid the C++ Standard Library, you should be using it if you're programming in C++.  That's where the benefits are.

Comment: @HostileFork: By `elaborate` I mean a heck of a lot of typing to do something that is trivial in ANSI-C.

Comment: @NikBougalis: The "How much am I using" will be changed a lot in this implementation (the array is a small buffer). Speed is of the essence, so I don't want to toy around with the extra cruft that std::vector gets me.

Comment: @ThomasKejser You may have very biased and misinformed understandings of what you are dealing with.  May I suggest a browse through of [Learning Standard C++ as a New Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf).  It's a short read, but perhaps it would encourage you to challenge what are likely misconceptions...and run some tests to realize that.  If C code is faster than C++ code, it's usually only because it's incorrect.

Comment: @HostileFork: I am not referring to the speed, but to the horrible syntax that std::array gives me. Would much prefer something more readable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62299/discussion-between-hostilefork-and-thomas-kejser).

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I forgot to add the const to the function. Added now

Comment: Since your function is `const` the caller should not be permitted to modify the data, ; so it has to return `Foo* const *`. Otherwise the caller would be able to modify a const object (without using a cast), causing undefined behaviour

Comment: @MattMcNabb you answer actually gives by far the nicest syntax. If you could file an answer, I would mark that as the winner.

Comment: @ThomasKejser beauty is in the eye of the beholder I guess -- I think it's better to have the address and the size wrapped up in a single unit, rather than having to take the size as a separate parameter. But glad it helped. (Note that you may want to use the const and non-const accessor pattern this way too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody posted an answer using `std::array` yet, it is a very simple replacement:

```
class Bar
{
    std::array<Foo *, 10>  m;
public:
    std::array<Foo *, 10> & getArray() { return m; }
    std::array<Foo *, 10> const & getArray() const { return m; }
};
```

This seems to me a lot simpler than the hoops you have to jump through to use your C-style array version.

To avoid code duplication you could `typedef std::array<Foo *, 10> FooArray;` .

The technique of having both a `const` and a non-`const` implementation is a common pattern for accessor functions which return a reference or a pointer. (It's not required if your accessor returns by value, of course).

Comment: This has the beauty of letting the caller know just how large the array is. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

I would seek to use a `std::array` or a `std::vector` in most cases. If you are determined to use a raw array then you could go this way with it:

```
typedef int Foo;

typedef Foo* (&FooPtrArrayRef)[10]; // to make the syntax less hairy

class Bar
{
private:
  Foo* m[10];

public:
  // First way without using typedef
  Foo* (&getArray())[10]
  {
      return m;
  }

  // Nicer looking way with a typedef
  FooPtrArrayRef getArrayByRef()
  {
      return m;
  }
};

int main()
{

    Bar b;

    Foo* (&array)[10] = b.getArray();

    std::cout << (sizeof(array) / sizeof(Foo*)) << '\n';

    // Alternative using "size deduction"

    Foo* (&array2)[sizeof(b.getArray()) / sizeof(Foo*)] = b.getArray();

    std::cout << (sizeof(array2) / sizeof(Foo*)) << '\n';

    // MUCH nicer using the typedef

    FooPtrArrayRef array3 = b.getArrayByRef();

    std::cout << (sizeof(array3) / sizeof(Foo*)) << '\n';
}
```

The syntax is pretty obscure though.

The benefits of this is approach is that it retains the full type information of the array you are passing by reference. The obscure syntax is necessary to avoid the type collapsing to a `Foo**`. By retaining the full type of the array you retain the ability to know its size at compile time using the `sizeof()` operator.

Comment: Of course, one could create an alias for `Foo(*)[10]` first. Also, I think you meant raw instead of compile-time array.

Comment: Absolutely you can typedef this to clear it up a lot. But about "raw" can that not get confused with a `Foo**`? I probably have the wrong terminology here though.

Comment: raw pointer == not a smart-pointer. raw array == just the array the language itself provides, not its library (not a container-class with an array). Anyway, classes are compile-time too.

Answer (score 0):

here's another approach that returns the array reference and the current size as a tuple:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {};

using FooBuffer = Foo*[10];

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar() 
  : _m { nullptr }
  {
      _m[0] = new Foo;
      _m[1] = new Foo;
      _items = 2;
  }

  ~Bar() {
      for(auto fp : _m)
        delete fp;
  }

  std::tuple<FooBuffer&, size_t> getInfo() {
      return std::make_tuple(std::ref(_m), _items);
  }
private:    
  Foo* _m[10];
  size_t _items;
};


int main() {
    Bar b;

    auto info = b.getInfo();
    FooBuffer& buf = std::get<0>(info);
    size_t items = std::get<1>(info);

    for(Foo** p = buf ; p != buf + items ; ++p) {
        std::cout << "Foo at " << std::hex << *p << std::endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```